# Python - Error populating values to spreadsheet (using xlsxwriter)

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, xlsxwriter

I have pulled some data from a xml file that looks as below:

```
Parent




Child




Action
new


ID
54467


Type
None


Group




Name
None


ID
ab



COMMENTS

HTRER


REMARKS
LKO


CUSTOMER
HELLO
```

In the above sample, the first row represent the header while the row below that represents the corresponding value. I am trying to have these written to a spreadsheet such that each header is written on first row with the corresponding value in the subsequent row. I am trying to do that using the code below but see that some of the values do not get written.

Given below is the code I am using to write it to a spreadsheet using xlsxwriter:

```
row = 0
col = 0
row1 = 1
col1 = 0

for elem in tree.iter():
    worksheet.write(row, col, elem.tag)
    for subelem in elem:
        worksheet.write(row1, col1, subelem.text)
col +=1
```

Could anyone advice as to why the values are not getting correctly or does the code above needs some edit. Thanks

Comment: You probably need to increment the `row` and `col` variables in some way. The only increment shown is outside the loop.

Comment: @jmcnamara could you please guide on this.